# Struggling to get the right output: condition based on date and time

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a program to display previous, 1 shift data:
There are total of 3 shifts:
Shift 1: 6 am to 2 pm
Shift 2: 2 pm to 10 pm
Shift 3: 10 pm to 6 am
So depending upon current time, I should be able to copy all the data from just the previous 1 shift.

I have been wrecking my brains on this for the past week, no luck till now, the program runs fine but the logic isn't right I feel.
I am getting other data too, that doesn't belong to the previous shift.

The first half of the code is to just display the right times depending on the current time

```
    Sub previous() 
    Worksheets("Previousshiftdata").Activate
    Dim x As String

    Range("A1").Value = Now

    'To display the shift time for correspondng data i.e. previous shift. this is done in cells E and F

        'To display correct date and time of shift 3
    If (TimeValue(Time) > TimeValue("6:00:00") And TimeValue(Time) <= 
TimeValue("14:00:00")) Then
        x = "Shift 3"
        Range("E1").Value = TimeValue("22:00:00")
        Range("F1").Value = TimeValue("6:00:00")
        Range("B1").Value = Date

         'To display correct date and time of shift 1
    ElseIf (TimeValue(Time) > TimeValue("14:00:00")) And (TimeValue(Time) <= TimeValue("22:00:00")) Then
        x = "Shift 1"
        Range("E1").Value = TimeValue("6:00:00")
        Range("F1").Value = TimeValue("14:00:00")
        Range("B1").Value = Date

        'To display correct date and time of shift 2
    ElseIf (TimeValue(Time) > TimeValue("22:00:00") And TimeValue(Time) <= TimeValue("23:59:59")) Or (TimeValue(Time) > TimeValue("00:00:00") And TimeValue(Time) <= TimeValue("6:00:00")) Then
        x = "Shift 2"
        Range("E1").Value = TimeValue("14:00:00")
        Range("F1").Value = TimeValue("22:00:00")
        If TimeValue(Time) > TimeValue("22:00:00") And TimeValue(Time) < TimeValue("23:59:59") Then
            Range("B1").Value = Date
        ElseIf TimeValue(Time) > TimeValue("00:00:00") And TimeValue(Time) <= TimeValue("6:00:00") Then
            Range("B1").Value = Date - 1
        End If
    End If



    Range("D1").Value = x

    Call previous_ClearCells
    Call previous_transfer

    End Sub

'to clear cells
    Public Sub previous_ClearCells()
    Sheets("Previousshiftdata").Activate
    Range("A3:J300").ClearContents

    End Sub
```

I am struggling with the following part of the code, please let me know if I am using the right logic:
I am trying to copy rows based on time and date.

```
    'to copy rows based on condition
    Public Sub previous_transfer()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long

    Dim mydate As Date
    Dim mytime As Date
    Dim mystatus As String

    'to find the last filled row in summary
    lastrow1 = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Summary").Activate


    'assign date, time and status of row item in Summary for comparison with previous shift time
    'to start populating data in reverse order to get the latest data first
    For i = lastrow1 To (lastrow1 - 150) Step -1
        mydate = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value
        mytime = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "B").Value
        mystatus = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "J").Value
        Sheets("Previousshiftdata").Activate
        lastrow2 = Sheets("Previousshiftdata").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'j indicates destination row no i.e. row no. in previoushift
        j = lastrow2 + 1
    'to get shift 3 data
        If (x = "Shift 3" And (mydate = Date - 1 And mytime > TimeValue("22:00:00"))) Or (mydate = Date And mytime > TimeValue("00:00:00") And mytime < TimeValue("6:00:00")) Then
            Sheets("Summary").Activate
            Sheets("Summary").Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "J")).Copy
            Sheets("Previousshiftdata").Activate
            Sheets("Previousshiftdata").Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(j, "J")).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'to get shift 2 data
        ElseIf ((mydate = Date) And (mytime > TimeValue("14:00:00")) And (mytime < TimeValue("22:00:00"))) Or ((mydate = Date - 1) And (mytime > TimeValue("14:00:00")) And (mytime < TimeValue("22:00:00"))) Then
            Sheets("Summary").Activate
            Sheets("Summary").Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "J")).Copy
            Sheets("Previousshiftdata").Activate
            Sheets("Previousshiftdata").Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(j, "J")).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'to get shift 1 data
        ElseIf (TimeValue("6:00:00") < mytime < TimeValue("14:00:00")) And (mydate = Date) Then
            Sheets("Summary").Activate
            Sheets("Summary").Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "J")).Copy
            Sheets("Previousshiftdata").Activate
            Sheets("Previousshiftdata").Range(Cells(j, "A"), Cells(j, "J")).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If

    'to clear clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next i

    Sheets("Previousstatus").Activate

    End Sub
```

Comment: The code looks big, however, the first part is just for display, shouldn't have posted that. The main logic is in the latter part of the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struggling with logic in VBA: includes Date & TIme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931186/struggling-with-logic-in-vba-includes-date-time)